# How to remove matched record from both table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove matched record from both table if i click remove. Here matching except last column only because last column remove button. My code is not working: if I click remove all matched tr removing but I want which row I have clicked remove button in both tables that matched row only remove. How can I do it?

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/d4yzrtwn/3/

```
$(function(){
$('.remove').on('click', function(e){
    $('#T1 tbody tr').each(function(){
    var row = $(this);
    var left_cols = $(this).find("td").not(':last');
    $('#T2 tbody tr').each(function(){
        var right_cols = $(this).find("td").not(':last');
        if(left_cols.html() == right_cols.html()) { 
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
         }
     });

     $(this).closest('tr').remove();

  });
  });
 });
```

Comment: I want to remove same data if i click remove button

Comment: I want to remove same tr data  if i click remove button..but in my code if i click remove button all matching record removing..How to resolve this issue? i want to remove one by one if i click remove button

Comment: One by one means row by row...If you see my fiddle you can understand

Comment: Simple:I am trying to remove same data from both table. One by one this means which row remove i clicked that row only remove from both table.

Comment: And you want to avoid removing all the records and keep one, right?

Comment: I am trying to remove same data from both table. One by one this means which row remove button i clicked that row only remove from both table  same data..Next which row remove button i clicked that row only remove from both table same data.....

Comment: @Debendra..Now you understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compare html content based on selected row's table with correspondent table.

Selection is dynamic, meaning works visa-versa and restricts remove on non-matching records.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.remove').click(function() {
    let clicked_row = $(this).closest('tr');
    let clicked_table = clicked_row.closest('table tbody').find('tr');
    clicked_table.each(function() {
      if (clicked_row.closest('table').attr('id') === 'T1') {
        opponent_table = $('#T2 tbody tr');
      } else {
        opponent_table = $('#T1 tbody tr');
      }
      opponent_table.each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() === clicked_row.html()) {
          $(this).remove();
          clicked_row.remove();
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="T1" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Suffix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>84</td>
      <td>96</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bat</td>
      <td>man</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table id="T2" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Suffix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bat</td>
      <td>man</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>james</td>
      <td>bond</td>
      <td>007</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/debendraoli/qvy0dLfh/33/

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){
   $('.remove').on('click', function(e){
      var content = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").text().trim();
      $("#T1 tbody tr, #T2 tbody tr").each(function(e){
         if($(this).text().trim() === content){
           $(this).remove();
         }
      });
   });
});
```

change your script to this. you don't have to do that all checks

Comment: This one doesn't meet all the requirements: "I am trying to remove matched record from both table"

Answer (score -2):

@cinan

This code will do the job. It's more clear and readable. If you have any further questions please let me know.

```
$(function(){
  $('.remove').on('click', function(e) {
    var $removedRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var removedRowHtml = $removedRow.html();
    var $clickedTable = $(this).closest('table');

    var $anotherTable = $('table').not($clickedTable);

    $('tr', $anotherTable).each(function(k, entry) {
      if ($(entry).html() === removedRowHtml) {
        $(entry).remove();
      }
    });

    $removedRow.remove();
  });
});
```

You can check it here as well: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdpMQP

Comment: Unmatched record also deleting

Comment: I disagree. Can you provide more details?

Comment: your codes does not works via visa-versa (both side).

Comment: I do really want to understand what is wrong with this answer but I am not able to. The code I provided works exactly as cinnan wants. It works visa-versa, both side or whatever you call it.